# How do you enable auto correct for an HTML textbox in IE9 mobile?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, mo

I have an input textbox on a web form that is being viewed on IE9 mobile, and I'm unable to figure out how to enable auto correct.  It would appear that the attribute `autocorrect=on` is the trick for webkit browsers, but if there is an attribute/class for IE9 mobile, I haven't been able to find it.

For reference, here is what I have for the textbox currently:

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subjectField" value="" autocorrect="on" />
```

Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, `autocorrect` attribute is at this date only implemented on Safari rendering engine. No other browsers provide this feature through `autocorrect` attribute. There are [discussions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=943690#c28) going on about this topic